# What does "intake" of central intake mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology

I was at the Employment and Social Services office and they gave me a leaflet that contains a list of useful numbers to call. One of the numbers is for *Central Intake*. It is for homeless individuals and families who are in need of emergency shelter.

Does *central* here means it's an office that has power or control over other parts? What about *intake*, what does it mean?

I couldn't find an appropriate definition from the dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merriam-Webster Unabridged says:

> **intake**, *n*. **3a** : the act, process, or an instance of taking in
>
> *specifically* : initial procedures (as interviews) conducted by a social worker, juvenile-court officer, or clinician in considering a
>   client for treatment or service

*Central Intake* is apparently the main location for processing in those applying for emergency shelter.

Comment: For some reason I like this definition better. I actually tried calling the number and pretended to be a homeless and they did actually conduct a series of interviews asking me questions like my name, where I live, my financial situation, etc.. to see if I'm eligible for shelter.

Answer (score 2):

[Intake](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intake): an act of taking people into an organization.

It seems likely that "Central Intake" controls the admission of the homeless and those requiring shelter into suitable emergency accommodation.

Comment: Still sounds like a ventilation duct for central air to me. :)